# How to fetch large images from discogs api?

Tags: android, json, albumart, discogs-api

Is it possible to get higher quality images from discogs api? Right now I can only get a thumbnail image of size 150x150. Is there any way for developers to get a better quality image? The JSON only has link for thumnail images.

So if this is my request

```
https://api.discogs.com/database/search?page=1&per_page=1&key=my_key&secret=my_secret&q=Waka%20Waka
```

This is the response that I get

```
{  
   "pagination":{  
      "per_page":1,
      "items":1731,
      "page":1,
      "urls":{  
         "last":"https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=Waka+Waka&per_page=1&secret=my_secret&page=1000&key=my_key",
         "next":"https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=Waka+Waka&per_page=1&secret=my_secret&page=2&key=my_key"
      },
      "pages":1000
   },
   "results":[  
      {  
         "style":[  
            "Alternative Rock",
            "Jazz-Rock",
            "Fusion"
         ],
         "thumb":"https://api-img.discogs.com/YokvweulGO7tRuNoSv3b1F4UntQ=/fit-in/150x150/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/R-1378139-1466530254-6813.jpeg.jpg",
         "format":[  
            "Vinyl",
            "LP",
            "Album"
         ],
         "country":"US",
         "barcode":[  
            "(31,456) RE I",
            "(31,457) RE I",
            "MS-2094 31456-1",
            "MS-2094 31457-1",
            "S1\u00b7MS 2094A 31456-Re1-T2 ",
            "25 MS 20941 31457 Re1\u00b7T2",
            "ASCAP"
         ],
         "uri":"/Frank-Zappa-Waka-Jawaka-Hot-Rats/master/35744",
         "community":{  
            "have":3089,
            "want":1992
         },
         "label":[  
            "Bizarre Records",
            "Reprise Records",
            "Warner Bros. Records Inc.",
            "Warner Bros. - Seven Arts Records, Inc.",
            "Warner Bros. Records Inc.",
            "Warner Bros. Records Inc.",
            "Munchkin Music",
            "Paramount Studios"
         ],
         "catno":"MS 2094",
         "year":"1972",
         "genre":[  
            "Rock"
         ],
         "title":"Frank Zappa - Waka / Jawaka \u2022 Hot Rats",
         "resource_url":"https://api.discogs.com/masters/35744",
         "type":"master",
         "id":35744
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to have larger images, how can I do that? Is that even possible? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search for releases you get an `id` that you can use to get more release info.

Make call to `https://api.discogs.com/releases/{id}?key={your_key}&secret={your_secret}`

Response usually has some image urls that you can download.